# How can we select all paragraphs when button or (toggle) is pressed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out I want when I press button and selected all paragraphs and changing font-color but I cant I was trying

```
<script>
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.querySelector('p').style.color = "blue";  
});
</script>
```

working code but only 1 paragraph so  after I was trying

```
<script>
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('p').style.color = "blue";  
});
</script>
```

doesn't work ...
I tried giving the same id tag to all the paragraphs, but again only 1 of them worked.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` iterable, you can't just assign values to `style` (NodeList does not have any such attribute). Loop the members of the returned `NodeList` and apply the style to each.

Comment: Duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `document.querySelectorAll('p')` returns an array, you need to loop and set the color.

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  let allP = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  for(let i=0; i<allP.length; i++)
  {
    allP[i].style.color = "blue"; 
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<p>para1</p>
<p>para2</p>
<p>para3</p>
```